# Calculating $-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, fractions

Hello everyone I have the following question.

I have the following fraction$$f(x)=-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$

But how would I reduce it? I know I have to multiply the opposite numerator by denominator and I got:
\begin{gather*}
(x-1)^2(4)=4x^2-8x+4\\
1(x^2)=x^2
\end{gather*}

So I got:$$f(x)=-\frac{4x^2-8x+4+x^2}{x^2(x-1)^2}$$

But this is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.
Your mistake was applying the "-"
to both terms instead of just one.

You wrote
$f(x)=-\frac{4x^2-8x+4+x^2}{x(x-1)^2}$.

What you should have is
$f(x)=\frac{-(4x^2-8x+4)+x^2}{x(x-1)^2}
=\frac{-4x^2+8x-4+x^2}{x(x-1)^2}
=\frac{-3x^2+8x-4}{x(x-1)^2}
$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now I have to find what x could be...

Comment: Thanks for the help I see now $(-3x+2)(1x-2)$

Answer (score 3):

Already answered, but I would like to point out the reduction:

$$f(x) = -{(3 x-2)(x-2)\over x^2 (x-1)^2}$$